# Microsoft Bot C# SDK During a WaterfallStepContext using adaptive card attachment get error from card submit action

Tags: c#, botframework, submit, adaptive-cards

I tried many idea without any success getting the next error in the Emulator:
[image]

Contsructor contains all step of WaterfallDialog:

```
AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                InitialStepAsync,
                CollectDataStepAsync
            }));
            AddDialog(new TextPrompt(nameof(TextPrompt)));

            // The initial child Dialog to run.
            InitialDialogId = nameof(WaterfallDialog);
```

In InitialStepAsync I attached the Card. It works, please see the picture:

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> InitialStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/
            var adaptiveCard = CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment();
            var response = MessageFactory.Attachment(adaptiveCard, ssml: "Create Impulse Ticket!");
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(response, cancellationToken);

            var opts = new PromptOptions
            {
                Prompt = new Activity
                {
                    Type = ActivityTypes.Message,
                    Text = "waiting for user input...", // You can comment this out if you don't want to display any text. Still works.
                }
            };
            // Display a Text Prompt and wait for input
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), opts);
        }
```

In CollectDataStepAsync I would like to catch the result of Card after pressing the button, please see the picture:

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> CollectDataStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/botframework-reactive-adaptive-cards-how-to-read-data-on-action-buttons-in-adap2/
            dynamic val = stepContext.Context.Activity.Value;
            //await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(val.id_number);

            /*var activity = stepContext.Context.Activity;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(activity.Text) && activity.Value != null 
                //&& activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message // Ensure that message is a postBack (like a submission from Adaptive Cards)
                && activity.ChannelData != null)
            {
                var token = JToken.Parse(activity.ChannelData.ToString());
                string selectedcolor = "**Nothing**";
                if (System.Convert.ToBoolean(token["postback"].Value<string>()))
                {
                    JToken commandToken = JToken.Parse(activity.Value.ToString());
                    string command = commandToken["action"].Value<string>();

                    if (command.ToLowerInvariant() == "colorselector")
                    {
                        selectedcolor = commandToken["choiceset"].Value<string>();
                    }

                }
                // await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync($"You Selected {selectedcolor}", cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(activity.ChannelData.ToString());
            }*/
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync($"INPUT: {stepContext.Result}");
            return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(nameof(WaterfallDialog), cancellationToken);
        }
```

JSON file of Card attachment

```
{
  "$schema": "https://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.0",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "Input.Text",
      "id": "id_text"
    },
    {
      "type": "Input.Number",
      "id": "id_number"
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Submit",
      "data": {
        "prop1": true,
        "prop2": []
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What is the wrong? I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... here we go:

1. Change your OnTurnAsync method before base.OnTurnAsync(...). This is because Adaptive Cards sends a Json object and not a string value (ex. context.Activity.Text). Serialize your activity.Value. If you wanna use more Adaptive Cards in diferent Waterfall dialogs, this is the better option. You will save time. Here you go:

   ```
          var activity = turnContext.Activity;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(activity.Text) && activity.Value != null)
            {
                activity.Text = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(activity.Value);
            }
   ```

2.- Then in your next step (CollectDataStepAsync) you can collect the information like this:

```
var json = stepContext.Result.ToString();
```

3.- Deserialize it!

```
YourClass obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourClass>(json);
```

And that's all ;)